# Converting georeferenced .png files to .ecw using IrfanView

Tags: type-conversion, png, gis, irfanview

Is there anyway I can preserve image georeferencing information after processing or converting the image via IrfanView?
I have a couple of .png files with spatial reference and I'm trying to save them as ecw images. Unfortunately this process destroys the spatial reference vital for using the images in GIS software. If there was a way around this problem it would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: You'd be better served using a different Stack site.  This site is all about code.  Check out Geo Info Systems https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) to handle all your geospatial translation needs.

Assuming that you have a [PNG with a world file](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/png.html#raster-png) associated then you can easily convert to [ecw](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/ecw.html) (providing that the propitiatory ecw driver is compiled in).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, and thanks for your answer. I will have a look at gdal_translate.

Comment: I've tried a couple of things, but I can't find a good way to compile the ECW driver into my GDAL installation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I only use open formats.